# CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX СИ

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, консоль

Данная функция вроде как входит в windows.h но GCC отправляет меня нафиг с этой функцией.
Задание из универа, и необходимо чтоб код работал при компиляции прямо из консоли.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    short screenWidth = 192, screenHeight = 108, cs = 8;
    SMALL_RECT writeRegion = { 0, 0, 1, 1 };

    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HWND hWindow = GetConsoleWindow();

    CHAR_INFO *lpBuffer;

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdOut, TRUE, &writeRegion);

    COORD bufferSize = { screenWidth, screenHeight };

    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hStdOut, bufferSize);
    SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hStdOut);

    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fontInfo;
}
```

[image: вывод консоли]

Comment: какая версия gcc/mingw runtime'а? УМВР на кроссе i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-6.4.0/mingw64-runtime-5.0.3.

Comment: ->gcc -v                
-> blablabla........blablabla...... gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-3)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Скорее всего используется устаревший MinGW
Нужно установить что нибудь по новее, например MinGW-w64

Comment: справедливости ради, `_WIN32_WINNT` всё равно задать стоит... и версия `MinGW` поновее со свежими хедерами также будет всё поддерживать...

Answer (score 1):

Структура `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` доступна только начиная с Windows Vista. По всей видимости, у вас в качестве целевой задана более ранняя версия SDK. Попробуйте перед включением windows.h вставить такие строчки:

```
#define WINVER         _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
#define _WIN32_WINNT   _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

Подробнее про это можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt?view=vs-2017).

Comment: ничего не меняется, за исключеним лишь того, что теперь еще вначале два ворнинга по поводу редифайна.                                                                     
вот 1-й
s.c:3: warning: "WINVER" redefined
 #define WINVER         _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA

In file included from c:\mingw\include\w32api.h:59,
                 from c:\mingw\include\_mingw.h:73,
                 from c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:56,
                 from s.c:1:
c:\mingw\include\sdkddkver.h:190: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define WINVER _WIN32_WINNT

Comment: @владимир зайцев, ну вам же в сообщении об ошибке все расписали. Ваш компилятор использует свой `sdkddkver.h`, в котором задана целевая версия Windows NT. Разумеется, так ничего не выйдет. Либо как-то удаляйте этот файл, либо редактируйте его.

Comment: знать бы еще что именно там редактировать

Comment: @владимирзайцев, закоментировать (а лучше обернуть в #ifdef'ы) определение WINVER.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, `_WIN32_WINNT` тоже обязательно надо закомментировать. А проще отредактировать их до `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA`, а свои определения выкинуть. Ну я так думаю, я этот MinGW даже издали не видел.

Comment: позакрывал все дефы в sdkddkver.h ворнинги исчезли, а вот ошибка всеравно осталась. CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX - не понимает. Вообще мне эта структура нужна для того чтобы настроить шрифт консоли таким образом, чтобы он был квадратным, без интервалов и с настраиваемым размером "пикселя". Может это можно как то сделать без расширенной структуры?

Comment: просмотрел mingw64-runtime — `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` нигде не защищён по `WINVER`... хотя и `WINVER` ни где к гвоздями не прибита... @владимирзайцев, а чему равно значение `WINAPI_FAMILY`? и, возвращаясь к прежним баранам, какая именно версия mingw'шных биндингов используется?... не знаю, существует ли сегодня что-то окромя mingw64-runtime.

Comment: ->winapifamily.h #define WINAPI_FAMILY WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP

Comment: ->gcc -v -> blablabla........blablabla...... gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-

Comment: @владимирзайцев, это я уже видел, но любой тулчейн состоит из трёх частей: компилятор, линкер (binutils) и libc, версии и разработчики у них обычно разные (хотя и пересекающиеся).... mingw использует непосредственно виндовую libc, но поставляет для неё свои хедеры... сегодня обычно это `mingw-w64` (он же `mingw64-runtime`), но может быть и какой-то другой (я не знаю, есть ли они)... так вот, какая версия пакета системных хедеров, идущая с твоим компилятором?.. как именно посмотреть это под win я на вскидку не скажу...

Comment: компилятор я устанавливал ч-з MinGW instalation manager и MinGW - там помоему 32-битгный. На википедии написано вообще, что MinGW и MinGW-w64  - это разные вещи

Comment: вот еще такую строку нашел в _mingw.h ...->#define __MINGW32_VERSION           5000001L. Такая же есть в w32api.h к примеру

Comment: @владимирзайцев, даже забыл, что старый mingw ещё жив =)… собственно вот и ответ, в версии `mingw-org-wsl` `5.0.1` (если мы угадали с макросом `__MINGW32_VERSION`) структура `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` попросту [не объявлена](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/scm/git/mingw-org-wsl/blobs/89581f43949c2a7358e0e886dff3af6b9632869b/w32api/include/wincon.h), в свежей `5.2.0` она уже [есть](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/scm/git/mingw-org-wsl/blobs/5.2-trunk/w32api/include/wincon.h#ln368) и защищена соответствующей версией `_WIN32_WINNT`… так что или обновляйся, или объявляй её самостоятельно…